# Prevent multiple submit clicks on a form

Tags: javascript

My contact email form for some reason sometimes sends twice, sometimes although very rarely even three times. Nightmare.

I came to the conclusion that it must be multiple submit clicks.

My JS below doesn't work unfortunately.

Is there another way I can prevent more than one click(s) on the submit button?

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(DoubleClickHandler);

            function DoubleClickHandler(sender, args) { 

                var getPost = args.get_postBackElement(); 
                getPost.disabled = true; 

                }
    </script>
```

Comment: Try to store to variable if button was clicked (via boolean value for example) and check every time was the button clicked via `if(!wasClicked)`

Comment: @CommercialSuicide would you mind showing me?